# Getting minor device number from tty_nr attribute in /proc/pid/stat

Tags: c, linux, unix, operating-system, bit-manipulation

I am trying to extract the minor device number from the tty_nr attribute in /proc/pid/stat. According to the documentation it is said that, minor device number is a combination 0-7 and 20-30 bits in tty_nr. How can I extract these bits from the tty_nr number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are macros already defined for this purpose.  Use the `MAJOR()` and `MINOR()` macros that are defined in `linux/kdev_t.h`.

Comment: I have got the tty_nr from proc/stat, I want to know how I can extract the minor and major number from tty_nr.

Comment: Assuming you have the value in a variable called tty_nr, do this:

int major = MAJOR(tty_nr);
int minor = MINOR(tty_nr);

Comment: Strange because the header says: `#define MAJOR(dev) ((dev)>>8)` and `#define MINOR(dev) ((dev) & 0xff)` and the other way around: `#define MKDEV(ma,mi)    ((ma)<<8 | (mi))`. However, the `man proc` manual says: _The controlling terminal of the process.  (The minor device number is contained in  the  combination of bits 31 to 20 and 7 to 0; the major device number is in bits 15 to 8.)_ Yet the macros do not take bits 31 to 20 in account. Which one is correct?